# C++ Number of Secs Since Epoch with given Hour and Minute

Tags: c++, time, epoch

I am trying to get the number of seconds from epoch (1970 Jan 1) with a given valid hour and minute.

Assuming the hour given is 10 and the minute given is 30, which would mean it's 10:30AM. Also on the assumption that it is on today's date. Meaning it would be:

2014 Dec 6 10:30:00 AM

How can I get the number of seconds from epoch to the above date?

I have tried the following but I get -1 as my result.

```
time_t now = time(0);
tm *ltm = gmtime(&now);

struct tm t;
t.tm_year = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
t.tm_mon  = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
t.tm_mday = ltm->tm_mday;
t.tm_hour = 10;
t.tm_min  = 30;
t.tm_sec  = 0;
time_t timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
```

timeSinceEpoch returns -1. Why is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [mktime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) like following

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);//Getting current time.

struct tm t = {0};             // Initalize to all 0's
t.tm_year = timePtr->tm_year;  // This is year- 114 (1900+114=2014)
t.tm_mon = timePtr->tm_mon;    //Current Month
t.tm_mday = timePtr->tm_mday;  //Today's date
t.tm_hour = 10;                //Time you need (10)
t.tm_min = 30;                 //Minutes you need (30)
t.tm_sec = timePtr->tm_sec;    //Current second
time_t timeSinceEpoch = mktime(&t);
```

Comment: I would like to get the year, month, day from the system instead. Only the hour, minute and seconds fields are set through variables. Can I know why is tm_year = 114?

Comment: @Wallace :: I had edited the code to meet your need. Also note that tm_year will be the years since 1900.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting 1417833000 as my result. Is this correct? Is there a way to verify the result? I'm using gmtime by the way. Is there a difference between gmtime and localtime? My timezone is GMT+8.

Comment: You can verify it through http://www.epochconverter.com/ & 1417833000 =>GMT: Sat, 06 Dec 2014 02:30:00 GMT